# Matching two strings allowing a single swap

Tags: java, string, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-search

I am running a fuzzy match algorithm, that allows two strings to have a single difference by Levenshtein metrics. But there is a frequent misprint when two consequent letters are swapped:

> Jo**na**than -> Jo**an**than
>
> profes**si**onal ->  profes**is**onal

but those differencies give 2 by Levenshtein. How do I match those differencies also?

Comment: I suppose 'Joannthan' in the first example is a typo? Because this is a swap and an additional 'n'.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Fixed. Thanks for drawing my attention to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is the [Damerau–Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance). It's the Levenshtein distance including adjacent transpositions.